# Is the intercept term in a linear regression model the intercept term?

Tags: r, regression, linear-model, intercept

Currently working through some notes on linear regression and they say the following:

In the linear model:
$$Y=\alpha+\beta x$$ the intercept term is the mean value of the response."

However, I've been working through some examples in `R`, and for the two models I've fitted, `R` gives me an estimate for the intercept parameters that is not equal to the mean value of the response variables. Why is this so ?

Comment: If the quote hasn't omitted some relevant context, it's wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, intercept estimate is calculated as follows:
$$\hat \alpha = \bar y - \hat\beta \bar x$$
In order for $\hat\alpha$ be equal to mean response, you'll need $\bar x=0$. This happens either by chance or if you standardize your features first and do the regression.